# OpenSSL create both keys at once

Tags: openssl

Is there any way to create private and public keys with one command? 
The classic way is two commands

*$openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 2048*

and after that

*$openssl rsa -in privkey.pem –pubout –out pubkey.pem*

I tried with | (pipe) but no.

Comment: Why not use `&&`?

Answer (score 1):

OK, since noone is trying to answer this I have few tips. OpenSSL doesn't seem to know that.

1. If you need to use pipe with the private key in stdin, you can use following. E.g. to output the pubkey right away (in fact, it is useless since you don't save the privkey):

   `openssl genrsa 2048 | ....`

   `openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl rsa -pubout`
2. You can use `ssh-keygen` for similar thing. The following will print the pub/priv rsa key pair with empty passphrase, but afaik it's in a bit different format than the OpenSSL would give you.

   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f file -P ""`
3. And then there is the fact that using `&&` or two separate commands should be okay for most situations.

Answer (score 0):

openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days XXX

see the accepted answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-build-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl)

Comment: That produces a privatekey and a selfsigned cert, which is sometimes useful but not what was asked. For what was asked on Unixoid systems `openssl genrsa ... | tee private.pem | openssl rsa -pubout >public.pem`. Or in 1.0.0+ you can use `genpkey` and `pkey` instead, but for RSA there's no benefit.